# Dynamically populate object properties with dictionary values

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, properties, initialization, populate

In Objective-C, I have a dictionary:

```
firstName -> John
lastName -> Smith
age -> 34
```

and an object `Person` that has corresponding instance variables and properties (that handle memory management appropriately). I'd like to create a convenience initializer that takes a dictionary as an argument and populates all the object fields (via their properties for memory management purposes) from the dictionary keys/values, instead of manually doing something like:

```
obj.firstName = [dict objectForKey:@"firstName"];
obj.lastName = [dict objectForKey:@"lastName"];
obj.age = [dict objectForKey:@"age"];
....
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/):

```
[obj setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dict];
```

See also [the documentation for `-setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:).

Comment: Is there a similar method to go the other way (convert object to dictionary)?

Comment: @ebi `-dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:`, whose documentation is on the same page.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you need to declare the keys - I'm looking for a simpler way..

Comment: @ebi The runtime has no idea what selectors on your object correspond to keys. If a method to get all the properties on your object existed, it would have to call every method that has the right signature. Is `- (MyObject *)newObject` a method which creates a new object, or a method which returns the value of the `newObject` property?

Comment: A new instance of the object?

Comment: @ebi I'm asking hypothetically, because it has the same signature as any property, so a hypothetical "dictionary of all properties" would need to call that method (and any similar one), despite having no idea whether it is actually a property.